# Python os.getenv on OSX (Django 1.4)

Tags: python, django, linux, macos

I just updated an environment to Django 1.4. On syncdb's first run I get the following error:

```
TypeError: decode() argument 1 must be string, not None
```

This error is triggered by `django/contrib/auth/management/init`:

```
try:
    return getpass.getuser().decode(locale.getdefaultlocale()[1])
except (ImportError, KeyError, UnicodeDecodeError):
    # KeyError will be raised by os.getpwuid() (called by getuser())
    # if there is no corresponding entry in the /etc/passwd file
    # (a very restricted chroot environment, for example).
    # UnicodeDecodeError - preventive treatment for non-latin Windows.
    return u''
```

`getdefaultlocale` returns `None`

After reading [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16017#comment:24) Django ticket, I tried the unofficial patch which worked, however I think I could do better by figuring out what happends..

So I opened a python command line, and tried:

```
import os
print os.getenv()
None
os.getenv.__doc__
"Get an environment variable, return None if it doesn't exist.\n    The optional second argument can specify an alternate default."
```

Could I solve this issue within OSX itself? Tips are welcome

Comment: It's an open bug on django. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16017

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The immediate resolution for this, assuming you are using bash as your shell:

`$ export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`

`$ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

This will set your locale for that session, and syncdb will work. You can add this to your profile and make it permanent for your shells.

You can use the `locale` command to see the current settings, and `locale -a` to see what locales are available to you. `en_US.UTF-8` is a generic safe one, but you may have other preferences.

Comment: I figured an export flag would work, but I was wondering if OSX shouldn't already do this internally. Obviously your awnser is better then hacking Django's core, thanks

Comment: Thank you! Finally someone explains how to fix this. :)